# Необходимо получить изображение, которое прислал пользователь по такому принципу: /команда [фото]. Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Нужно скачать на диск изображение, которое прислал пользователь с помощью команды. Бот в телеграмме библиотека Aiogram по типу: /команда [фото]. Буду очень признателен объяснениям. Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит /команда [фото]? Что в этом "фото"? Айди?

Comment: Объясните как вы это видите по пунктам.

Comment: Итак, пользователь пишет команду условно назовем команду /photo и прикрепляет фотографию к команде. И бот должен скачать именно эту фотографию, которая была отправлена при помощи команды. На данный момент я могу качать только все файлы подряд, такого мне не нужно, ведь фотография которую прислали должна сохраняться. И ещё по другой команде показываться пользователю. Типа заметок. При повторном использований /photo предыдущее фото должно удалиться, и сохраниться новое. Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Простите, если много воды. Спасибо за вашу активность.

Comment: Безусловно можно хранить просто айди фотографии, но опять же как мне сохранить айди именно той фотографии, которая была отправлена с командой, а не все подряд. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @oleksandrigo уточнил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение:**
Встроенный фильтр `commands_ignore_caption=False` , который по умолчанию True отвечает за проверку команд под всякими разными файлами.

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands = ["new"], commands_prefix = "/!", commands_ignore_caption=False, content_types=["photo"])
async def new(message: types.Message):
        file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
        print(file_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def message_text(message: types.Message):
        await message.photo[-1].download('img/am.jpg')
```

После скачивания в консоли появляется сообщение об ошибке, но она ничему не мешает

Comment: Нет, нет вы не поняли. Про этот способ я знал. Меня интересует такой метод /команда + прикрепленное фото. В вашем коде бот будет скачивать все изображения. А мне нужно только то, что было отправлено по данному шаблону /команда [фото]. Спасибо за ответ.